# jquery UI image is resizable but not draggable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following script that allows me to resize the image, however, I am not able to drag the image around and change its position

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
   <div class="div1">
   <h1> About Us </h1>

   <p class="card-text">
    general description 
   </p>

   
   <div id="draggableHelper"  style="display:inline-block">
    <img id="image"  src = "images/jimslogo2.png"/>
    </div>
   </div>


   <div class="div2">
    <span class="dot">


    <div>
    <div id="rotator"></div>
    </div>

     <p class="textScale">
       <b>Featured Products </b>
     </p>
    </span>
   </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#draggableHelper').draggable();
  $('#image').resizable();
  
  });
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

The image I'm trying to drag is contained in its own div tag within the "row" class div. I'm not sure this isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Use these two links instead.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can try my answer here https://jsfiddle.net/a68mdzes/

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

What is your purpose in the draggable, you need to define the options for it

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
   <div class="div1">
   <h1> About Us </h1>

   <p class="card-text">
    general description 
   </p>

   
   <div id="draggableHelper">
    <img id="image"  src = "images/jimslogo2.png"/>
    </div>
   </div>


   <div class="div2">
    <span class="dot">


    <div>
    <div id="rotator"></div>
    </div>

     <p class="textScale">
       <b>Featured Products </b>
     </p>
    </span>
   </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#draggableHelper').draggable();
  $('#image').resizable();
  
  });
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have two versions of jQuery (3.5.1 & 1.9.1) in your script. You are also using an older version of jQuery UI (1.9.2). It would be best to ensure you are using the latest versions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#draggableHelper').draggable();
  $('#image').resizable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="div1">
    <h1> About Us </h1>
    <p class="card-text">general description</p>
    <div id="draggableHelper" style="display:inline-block">
      <img id="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.png&text=IMAGE" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <span class="dot">
    <div>
    <div id="rotator"></div>
    </div>
     <p class="textScale">
       <b>Featured Products </b>
     </p>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above test allows for both to work as expected. You will notice I am using only one version of jQuery and jQuery UI.